# Audio Recording iPhone app using separate microphones

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation, ios-appstore, microphone

I want to make a 2-element microphone array using my iPhone. I'm looking for an audio recording app (like Voice Memos) that can record through both microphones of the iPhone.
Does anybody know an application for this purpose?

Comment: My first question would be… "What are you trying to achieve?".  As it stands, it's unclear what you 'need' vs 'what you 'think you need'

Comment: I need the data of two seperate microphones placed at a certain distance to analyse them for localization of the source (it's  my b.sc project)

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes sense. It might be best if you edit that into your original question to make it clearer. Also whether you need this to be recorded as 2 separate tracks/stereo pair etc. I don't know of an app that can use the internal mics that way, but [IKMultimedia](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/cat-view.php?C=mobile) do a lot of external mic/recording app combinations. The Field mic might be a possibility - http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irigmicfield/